# Removing an attribute after my page has already loaded

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typescript, video.js

I am not sure the best way to describe my issue, but essentially I have a CSS attribute being added my div tag that I believe comes from a node module and I am unable to see it anywhere in my files. I was wondering if there was a way to remove this specific attribute from the div tag because it's creating a large black background behind my video player that also extends my webpage unnecessarily. If I manually delete if after the web page loads then everything looks as it should

in the first div tag in the image i linked there is an attribute called vjs_video_3-dimensions at the end of the class tag and im wondering if its possible to stop that from loading

[image: this is the issue im having]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, they're unhelpful, inaccessible, non-searchable, discriminate against those with visual impairments, and preclude reproducing your code in order to help you. Post code as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery or plain JavaScript.

with jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#vjs_video_3" ).removeClass( "vjs_video_3-dimensions" );
});
```

with JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function( event ) {
    let el = document.getElementById( "vjs_video_3" );
    el.classList.remove( "vjs_video_3-dimensions" );
});
```

And finally, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2j86nqsw/

Comment: Thank you i will try  that when i get home, i tried something similar with jquery but the way you showed looks like it's more relevant to what i actually need to do, thank you